# Swift iOS: How to assign a value to a Label created with Tag system

Tags: ios, swift, tags, label, uilabel

After creation of a list of Label created with this func:

```
func addElongationlabel() {
        let elongationLabel = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: ordinata, width: 90, height: 35))
        elongationLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        elongationLabel.tag = ordinata
        elongationLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
        elongationLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        view.addSubview(elongationLabel)
    }
```

I'm obtaining a list of label using this cycle of For:

```
for i in 1...Int(numberOfDiesText.text!)!{
     ordinata = 220 + 50*i

        addElongationlabel()

    }//end of for
```

Now I want to assign to my Labels a value calculated. I'm trying with this code but it is not working:

```
for i in 1...Int(numberOfDiesText.text!)!{
     ordinata = 220 + 50*i

        if let eloLabel = (self.view.viewWithTag(ordinata)as? UILabel){
     // here I think I have to insert the correct command
        self.view.viewWithTag(ordinata) = eloLabel // this is not working...of course
        }

    }//end of for
```

Thank you to help me!

Comment: Why are you creating a `UITextView` in your `addElongationlabel`? I thought it was supposed to be a `UILabel`. Also, what are you trying to do with `eloLabel`. Are you trying to change the label's text?

Comment: Are you trying to pass `ordinata` from the loop to `addElongationlabel`?

Comment: above you are initializing textview, and getting from tag as uilabel.
however if you want your object, you will have to typecast your view you get from tag, like
(view.viewWithTag(x) as! uitextview) = textview

Comment: Also, you seem to be reinventing a `UITableView`. Please look that up. It will be much easier to manage than separate text views/labels.

Comment: I want to create the UILabel in this way because a priori I don't know how many labels I will enter into my View. After  creating the needing UILabels I have to assign to them a calculated value. What I want to do is something like that: Label (with tag= ordinata).text = CalculatedString. I hope to be clear( sorry I'm not a professional developer)

Comment: To Rob, yes UITextView should be changed in UILabel.